# Deployment Diagram for MVC pattern with Laravel and Inertia

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, deployment, uml, deployment-diagram

I am trying to make a deployment diagram for my web application. I am using MVC architectural pattern but I am unsure if this should be included:

[image: My Deployment diagram]

I am using reactjs, Inertia js, laravel and MySQL. How can I show this on my diagram?
I am not really sure how to represent Inertia JS

Comment: Can you confirm that your web-server runs node js for server side rendering, and that the eloquent component runs on that server, and that between the web server and the db server it's the db connection middleware taking charge?  Last but not least:  is the model the eloquent model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This diagram is a good start and all depends on the level of detail you want to share. You could indeed give a very high level picture of your architecture:

[image]

But this does not give good picture of the details that you provide:

- [Laravel](https://fkrihnif.medium.com/understanding-the-mvc-architecture-in-laravel-a-comprehensive-guide-8f620cc139b6) means that the components are executed in an enclopsing PHP exectution environment, the [PHP interpreter](https://medium.com/@andreibirta95/apache-web-server-architecture-with-php-basics-657a091d460f).
- [Eloquent ORM](https://stackify.com/laravel-eloquent-tutorial/) is not really the connection (this is why I preferred *ORM connection* insted of *Eloquent ORM*).  Eloquent is a component that supports your model that extends eloquent classes. I also understand that it's part of Laravel
- I understand that you're doing [server side rendering](https://inertiajs.com/server-side-rendering), as you don't show any js on the browser.  But I have to confess that I'm not very knowledgeable about Laravel & Inertia.  In this case, you'd certainly have a node.js execution server on your webserver as well. If not, you'll understand the principles and be able to fine tune the diagram to your needs.
- Regarding Inertia, I ualso nderstand that there is a js client side component to install for react, and a server side for laravel.

[image]

Now this is quite detailed already, and I've not even shown the dependencies between the components.  Maybe it's more than what you want to provide.  A simpler way could then to define some own stereotypes to show what's done with laravel:

[image]